# HTML Image Changing Position

Tags: html, css, image, stretch

I have images on my website (for now, I'm using height and width giving a number in pixels) but what I have noticed is that when I stretch my browser, my images tend to get totally messed up.

So I need a little help making them static so if a user stretches their browser, the pictures will stay in their position without getting moved around. At this point, my google chrome browser has to be stretched a certain amount for all of the pictures to be aligned inline. But once I stretch it, the pictures start to move. I want some way of keeping the pictures static.

If anyone can help me with this, it will be highly appreciated! Any advice/suggestions would really be nice! I've been struggling with this for a while now. 
Thanks!
Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "scrolling">
    <div class = "quick-info"> <!--Start quick-info-->
       <div class="image"> <!--Start1-->
         <img src="http://d39ya49a1fwv14.cloudfront.net/wp- content/uploads/2013/07/0x600.jpg" height="340" width="250"/>
       </div>
       <div class="image"> <!--Start2-->
         <img src="http://gstylemag.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Lebron-James-2.jpg" height="340" width="257"/>
       </div>
       <div class="image"> <!--Start3-->
         <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/President_Barack_Obama.jpg" height="340" width="257"/>
       </div> <!--End3-->
       <div class="image"> <!--Start4-->
         <img src="http://www.zooatlanta.org/media/image/panda_cubs2013_140402_meilun_meihuan_ZA_0769_600.jpg" height="340" width="257"/>
         </div> <!--End4-->
         <div class="image"> <!--Start5-->
          <img src="http://www.soflasun.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/dog8.jpg" height="340" width="259"/>
         </div> <!--End5-->
      </div> <!--End of quick-info-->
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

CSS:

```
.quick-info {
  background-color:#659CEF;
  height: 350px;
  font-family: Garamond;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.image {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  border: 0px;
}
#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 270px;
  width: 257px;
  height: 85px;
}
```

Comment: Are you using height:10% or height:50px? It shouldnt change if you are using px.

Comment: Can you post some more information? What does your code look like?

Comment: Sorry for posting it really late, but can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score -2):

If you increase the width of your browser window, the elements may be placed on the same line as each other if there is enough room ( depending on your positioning). Try changing the value of

> position:

In your stylesheet.

Also, I would reccomend you have a look into responsive frameworks such as bootstrap or foundation